# Accept dot or no dot at the end of nameserver

Tags: regex

This regex currently accept dot at the end of nameserver. What I need is: `ns1.test.com.` and `ns1.test.com` is accepted but not `ns1.test.com..`

```
var re = /^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\.)+[a-z]{2,3}\.$/i;
```

Help me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you requiring that the TLD be of two or three characters? What about `.info` and `.museum `?

Comment: I don't realize this. Thank for reminding me. Is this sufficient? `var re = /^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\.)+[a-z]{2,6}\.?$/i;`. Today is the first time of I heard the `.museum` domain. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional operator is, a `?`.

So just make the regex:

```
var re = /^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\.)+[a-z]{2,3}\.?$/i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `?`. It means "The previous character is optional".

```
/…\.?$/
```